# ERROR: Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I'm having trouble in deploying my django-react app.

This is my directory tree.

```
.
├── .elasticbeanstalk
└── backend
    ├── .ebextensions
    ├── auth
    │   ├── management
    │   │   └── commands
    │   └── migrations
    ├── client
    │   └── build
    │       └── static
    │           ├── css
    │           ├── js
    │           └── media
    ├── config
    │   └── settings
    ├── postings
    │   ├── management
    │   │   └── commands
    │   └── migrations
    └── uploads
```

```
# /.ebextensions/django.config
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: config/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

```
# /backend/config/wsgi.py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.deploy")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And application enviroment on aws website, WSGIPath: config/wsgi.py, NumProcesses: 3, NumThreads: 20

I can't find what should I fix.

Comment: Please note [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: oops. I didn't know. thanks.

Comment: First. What EB platform are you using - based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2? Second. Where is your `wsgi.py` file? Your file tree does not show that it exists.

Comment: @Marcin My EB platform is 'Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux', and ```wsgi.py```file is in ```backend/config ```.

Comment: Can you clarify what "having trouble in deploying" is? What trouble? Any error messages? have you inspected any EB logs for errors?

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for helping me sir. Here's my error log
```2020-12-02 10:21:48,499 ERROR    The specified WSGIPath of "config/wsgi.py" was not found in the source bundle```
and http://myapp-env...-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ returns me
```Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.```

Comment: @Marcin problem is that i can't see other error logs because it stucked by WSGI error.